# Calling multiple web services from the C# application

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json-deserialization

I am trying call a multiple services in one C# application. The response from one service is passed in as a input parameter to the other service. As the response first service is array of numbers, calling the other service in a for loop like  below

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
 {
 ......
 var response = await iLab_client.GetAsync(uri_serviceid);
 var datafile = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.ReqDTO.RootObject>(datafile);
 foreach (var req in returnDataObj.il_response.svc_req)
 {
   int request_id = req.id;

    //Calling the other service passing the input parameter

   using (var iLab_client_request = new HttpClient())
   {
    string request_Uri = BaseURL_iLab + "svc_req/"+request_id+"/c_forms.json";
    Uri uri_request = new Uri(request_Uri);
    client_request.BaseAddress = uri_request;
    client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
     var request_response = await client_request.GetAsync(uri_request);
     var responsefile = await request_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     var request_returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.DTO.RootObject>(responsefile);
     return Ok(request_returnDataObj);
  }}}
```

It trows error saying `'GetResponseFromiLabAPIController.Get()': not all code paths return a value` I understand that I need to create a object that can store the responses using the `Add()` and return it from outside the for loop. But I am not sure what should be the object type that can store all the responses from each service call.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the responses in a list.

```
public async Task<List<IHttpActionResult>> Get()
{
    ......

    var responses = new List<IHttpActionResult>>();
    var response = await iLab_client.GetAsync(uri_serviceid);
    var datafile = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.ReqDTO.RootObject>(datafile);
    foreach (var req in returnDataObj.il_response.svc_req)
    {
        int request_id = req.id;

        //Calling the other service passing the input parameter

        using (var iLab_client_request = new HttpClient())
        {
            string request_Uri = BaseURL_iLab + "svc_req/"+request_id+"/c_forms.json";
            Uri uri_request = new Uri(request_Uri);
            client_request.BaseAddress = uri_request;
            client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var request_response = await client_request.GetAsync(uri_request);
            var responsefile = await request_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var request_returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.DTO.RootObject>(responsefile);
            responses.Add(request_returnDataObj);
        }
    }
    return responses;
}
```